# why do I get heap-buffer-overflow in C?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (argc == 1)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  int count = 2;

  int i, j;
  for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < strlen(argv[i]); j++)
      count++;
  }

  printf("%d\n", count);

  char* original = malloc(sizeof(char) * count);
  printf("%p\n", original);
  char* copy = malloc(sizeof(char) * count);
  printf("%p\n", copy);
  memset(original, 0, strlen(original));
  memset(copy, 0, strlen(copy));

  strcpy(original, argv[1]);
  for (i = 2; i < argc; i++)
  {

    strcat(original, argv[i]);

  }

  int coun = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < strlen(original); i++)
  {
    if (original[i] == '(' || original[i] == '{' || original[i] == '[' ||
      original[i] == ')' || original[i] == '}' || original[i] == ']')
    {
      copy[coun] = original[i];
      coun++;
    }
  }

  printf("%s\n", original);
  printf("%s\n", copy);

  free(original);
  free(copy);
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I used **gcc -Wall -Werror -fsanitize=address balance.c -o balance** to make file
and **./balance '(('** to test

and I got this message

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn6yr.jpg)

what is the problem?

It is the code to get argv's contents and get only parenthesis on a string.

It might be error checking on `-fsanitize=address` I got it but I cannot find any errors on my code, so can someone check this please?

Comment: `strlen(original)` - what do you think it is supposed to return? `original` is not a string at all. Same with `strlen(copy)`

Comment: I declared with original with char* , isn't it string?

Comment: `string` in C  is not a type. It is a content. That is an array terminated by a null-character. Your arrays are uninitialized.

Comment: and my code works if I get rid of -fsanitize=address, so it should be the problem for memory maybe?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. It has an undefined behavior.

Comment: I just debugged it, and it works if I make file only using gcc -Wall -Werror balance.c -o balance

Comment: You might want to read about what [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) is.

Comment: hmm, then what do I have to do to make my code work?

Comment: I told you what your problem is. Do not use `strxxxx` functions on something which is not a string. You already know the sizes of the buffers though (`sizeof(char) * count`), you used them for `malloc`, so use the same for `memset`s.

Comment: `strlen(original)` will result in undefined behaviour if `original` does not point to a string. The memory returned by `malloc` is not initialized, it's content is undetermined.

Comment: `memset(original, 0, strlen(original))` -> `memset(original, 0, sizeof(char) * count);`

Comment: Use `calloc` instead of  `malloc`

Comment: BTW, do you know that `for (j = 0; j < strlen(argv[i]); j++)
      count++;` is completely equivalent to `count += strlen(argv[i])` ? If you don't need `j`.

Comment: Bonus: `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition, therefore you can drop it.

Comment: Thank you. I am really appreciated. I actually started learning C for 2 weeks ago, so it is kinda really confusing for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
memset(original,0,strlen(original));
memset(copy,0,strlen(copy));
```

Both `original` and `copy` point to memory returned by `malloc` which is *uninitialized*.  The `strlen` function reads the bytes pointed to by its argument until it finds a byte with value 0.  This means that 1) you're reading uninitialized memory, and 2) because the contents are indeterminate the function could read past the end of allocated memory.  Both of these actions trigger [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You know that both memory locations point to `count` bytes, so pass that to `memset`:

```
memset(original,0,count);
memset(copy,0,count);
```

Better yet, use `calloc` instead of `malloc` which returns memory that has been initialized to 0:

```
char* original = calloc(sizeof(char), count);
char* copy = calloc(sizeof(char), count);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem:

```
...
  char* original = malloc(sizeof(char) * count);
...
  memset(original, 0, strlen(original));
...
```

`strlen` is counting how many characters are there before encountering null byte `\0`. The memory allocated by `malloc` is uninitialized so you are not guaranteed to find any null byte before accessing memory you are not allowed to.